# celery receiving tasks but not returning results, just keeps pending

Tags: python, celery

```
from time import sleep
from celery import Celery

backend = 'db+sqlite:///db.sqlite3'

app = Celery('tasks', broker='amqp********************', backend=backend)


@app.task()
def reverse(text):
    sleep(5)
    return text[::-1]
```

So i have the above code, when i run the code it does not work celery just received the tasks and does nothing,
checking the status of the tasks i get pending
i use the below command to run celery, i have tried every other solution here, still the same.

```
celery -A tasks worker --loglevel=info
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use something like this,

```
celery -A tasks worker -l info --without-gossip --without-mingle --without-heartbeat -Ofair --pool=solo
```

i guess Celery will try to fetch tasks in batches from your broker

Comment: this worked for me as well! Would really appreciate if you could explain more about why ```celery -A tasks worker --loglevel=info``` does not work because that is the command I see on most tutorials